# JSON accessing values from Javascript variables came from select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON data whose values should be fetched using Javascript variables.

Here's the HTML

```
<body>

<form action="#" action="get">

    <select name="college" id="college" onchange="selection('college', 'course')">
        <option value="base">base</option>
        <option value="amity">Amity University</option>
        <option value="indraprastha">Indraprasth University</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <select name="course" id="course" >
        <option value="base">Base</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <select name="stream" id="stream"></select>

    <br>
    <select name="sem" id="sem"></select>

    <br>
    <select name="subject" id="subject"></select>

</form>
</body>
```

Here's the JSON

```
{
"amity": [
    {
        "name": "B.Tech,btech"
    },
    {
        "name": "M.tech,mtech"
    }
],

"indraprastha": [
    {
        "name": "B.Tech,btech"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mtech,mtech"
    }
]
}
```

and here's the JS

```
function selection(s1, s2) {
var first = document.getElementById(s1),
    second = document.getElementById(s2);

$.getJSON("json/list.json", function(data) {        
    var college = $('#college').val();

    $.each(data[college][0], function(key, value) {
        alert(value);

    });

  });
}
```

Now the problem is, using the first drop-down for college, I can get the value of college using `.val()` function. But for second drop-down which is dynamic, I want the values inside the college data array of JSON, but for some reason I am not able to access it unless appending an array index `[0]`, the reason for which I know, since it's array. But the value should come from course drop-down which is currently empty.

I want all the values inside the amity data array to go into second drop-down. Then from that I can access it like, `data[college][course]`

Are there any solutions for accessing the complete `amity` array and get all it's objects. Also, can you suggest article on creating at least 3-4 level dynamic drop-down menu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the array, you don't want `[0]`. The .each call will take care of iterating over the array, so `key` will actually be the index, and value will be the corresponding value. Since you have an array of objects, `value` will be a reference to an object, so you'll need to reference the name property: `value.name`. If you want to populate items in a select, though, I'd suggest you split out the value and the display text, rather than having them joined in what looks like a comma-separated string (i.e. change your JSON structure a bit).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thanks a ton, man...I wasted about 2 hours scratching head and finding what is wrong with my code.